# creating daily price change for a product on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a data set with the following columns:

order_id

order_item_id

product mrp

units

sale_date

I want to create a new column which shows how much the mrp changed from the last time this product was. This there a way I can do this with pandas data frame?

Sorry if this question is very basic but I am pretty new to pandas.

Sample data:
[image]

expected data:

For each row of the data I want to check the amount of price change for the last time the product was sold.

Comment: provide some sample data

Comment: And expected output too.

Comment: Hi terry and Valentino,  I have added the sample data and gave an explanation of the expected data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows:

```
# define a function that applies rolling window calculationg
# taking the difference between the last value and the current
# value
def calc_mrp(ser):
    # in case you want the relative change, just
    # divide by x[1] or x[0] in the lambda function
    return ser.rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[1]-x[0])

# apply this to the grouped 'product_mrp' column
# and store the result in a new column
df['mrp_change']=df.groupby('product_id')['product_mrp'].apply(calc_mrp)
```

If this is executed on a dataframe like:

```
Out[398]: 
   order_id  product_id  product_mrp  units_sold   sale_date
0         0           2   647.169280           8  2019-08-23
1         1           0   500.641188           0  2019-08-24
2         2           1   647.789399          15  2019-08-25
3         3           0   381.278167          12  2019-08-26
4         4           2   373.685000           7  2019-08-27
5         5           4   553.472850           2  2019-08-28
6         6           4   634.482718           7  2019-08-29
7         7           3   536.760482          11  2019-08-30
8         8           0   690.242274           6  2019-08-31
9         9           4   500.515521           0  2019-09-01
```

It yields:

```
Out[400]: 
   order_id  product_id  product_mrp  units_sold   sale_date  mrp_change
0         0           2   647.169280           8  2019-08-23         NaN
1         1           0   500.641188           0  2019-08-24         NaN
2         2           1   647.789399          15  2019-08-25         NaN
3         3           0   381.278167          12  2019-08-26 -119.363022
4         4           2   373.685000           7  2019-08-27 -273.484280
5         5           4   553.472850           2  2019-08-28         NaN
6         6           4   634.482718           7  2019-08-29   81.009868
7         7           3   536.760482          11  2019-08-30         NaN
8         8           0   690.242274           6  2019-08-31  308.964107
9         9           4   500.515521           0  2019-09-01 -133.967197
```

The `NaN`s are in the rows, for which there is not previous order with the same product_id.